# Подключение .obj файла VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер, visual-studio-2017, obj

[image: Подключенный obj]При попытке подключения .obj файла возникает ошибка  LNK1107 недопустимый или поврежденный файл: не удается прочитать по 0xDF    HLL D:\Aleksey\Учеба\C++\HLL\HLL\add_matrix.OBJ

Код проекта

```
#pragma comment(lib, "add_matrix")

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;


extern "C"
{
    char __cdecl add_matrix(const matrix& a, const matrix& b, matrix& c, const int size);
} 



int main()
{
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(NULL)));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size;

    std::cout << "Введите размерность матриц: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    matrix a(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0));
    matrix b (size, std::vector<int>(size, 0));
    matrix c (size, std::vector<int>(size, 0));


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::for_each(a[i].begin(), a[i].end(), [](int& x) {x = rand() % 10 + 1; });
        std::for_each(b[i].begin(), b[i].end(), [](int& x) {x = rand() % 10 + 1; });
    }


    char res = add_matrix(a, b, c, size);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Код файла add_matrix.asm(еще не дописал, хотел посмотреть в дебаге из вижуалки)

```
.486
.model flat
.data
    i db 0
.code
PUBLIC add_matrix
add_matrix proc near
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ;---------------------------
    mat_a equ dword ptr [ebp+8]
    mat_b equ dword ptr [ebp+12]
    mat_c equ dword ptr [ebp+16]
    n equ dword ptr [ebp+20]
    ;---------------------------
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ebx, mat_a

    ;
    pop ebp
    ret
add_matrix endp
end
```

Comment: obj - файл - может иметь разную фирму-производителя, и разную версию. Т.е. просто наличие obj-файла, не означает что вы его можете просто подключить к проэкту и всё. Borland-obj и Microsoft-obj например между собой не совместимы. Скорее всего производитель obj-файла не совпадает, или версия.

Comment: Ищите транслятор с ассемблера, совместимый с vs2017, лучше с её же папки bin Почитайте MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference

Comment: Возможно это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796300/assembly-programming-winasm-vs-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @nick_n_a я собирал с помощью tasm /ml add_matrix.asm.Это может быть из-за тасма?Я попробую сделать, как вы сказали.

Comment: @nick_n_a полученный с помощью vs2017 obj файл я подключил как на картинке выше, но ошибки возникают

Comment: @HideME, есть как минимум два кардинально разных варианта obj - форматы coff и ms coff (мало отличаются между собой, их выдает например masm и понимает линкер от microsoft) и omf (такой формат производили продукты бывшего borland, в том числе tasm). Линкер от microsoft объектные файлы формата omf не понимает. Есть конвертеры, но проще взять masm вместо уже наверное более десятилетия мертвого tasm'а.

Comment: @insolor я взял и с помощью масма в вижуалке сделал obj файл, но вижуалка кидает ошибки

Comment: Так напишите какие ошибки пишет

Comment: @insolor 32 ошибки LNK2019 
https://imgur.com/a/bCtMDqQ

Answer (score 2):

Неудивительно, что Visual Studio не понимает объектный файл, порожденный tasm. Для Visual Studio, видимо, придется пользоваться MASM.

В ASM файле укажите

```
.model flat,C
```

чтобы способ именования внешних символов совпадал с `extern "C"`.

Вся ваша возня с библиотеками и "подключение объектного файла" не обязательна. Вы можете просто добавлять MASM файлы в Visual Studio проект, как обычные C или C++ файлы. Они будут компилироваться MASM и собираться линкером по общей схеме. Ничего никуда не надо дополнительно подключать (если ваша цель не состоит в том, чтобы создать внешнюю библиотеку).

Каким образом (и зачем) вы собрались "разбирать" `std::vector` в ассемблере, правда, не ясно. Но то, что вы пока написали, прекрасно компилируется и собирается в Visual Studio.

Comment: Да, я после просто добавлял в проект файл ассемблера, выбирал в его свойствах масм, ставил галочку ещё в одном месте на масм, компилил, но были ошибки, сейчас попробую добавить то, что вы написали.Векторы я собирался складывать в той функции(задание сложение матриц).

Comment: @HideME: Такой ассемблерный файл компилируется только в 32-битной конфигурации. В 64-битной полезут ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: пробую писать .model flat, stdcall и extern "C" int __stdcall foo();
лезет ошибка линковки LNK2019

Comment: @HideME: Ну так а как выглядит имя функции в объектном файле, полученном из ассемблера? Почему вы не указали C в .model?